# htaccess not prompting for credentials on Ubuntu server

Tags: apache2, authentication, webserver

I created the following .htaccess file

```
<Files "index.php">
    AuthName "Restricted"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Files>
```

I generated a user and password using

```
sudo htpasswd -c /path/to/file/.htpasswd user password
```

When I navigate to the ip address it gave the message: "Unauthorized This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

According to all other walkthroughs It would indicate that I should be prompted for user and password but instead it is going straight to the error message. What do I have wrong? I don't need anything complex I just need it to prompt for password.

Comment: likely your .htpasswd -path (the one you do not mention above) is wrong. – it's not relative to your webroot, but an absolute path to your file system root as shown in `_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` (use `phpinfo()` to double check)

Answer (score -1):

Just check your browser console in the network menu for the current page request in the header tab.

[image: console]

if you sow `500 Internal Server Error` then there is some thing wrong in your server (`.htaccess` or `.htpassword` file). You should see `401 Unauthorized`if every thing is working fine.